# Load php dynamically from a dynamic javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dynamic, client-side

How can I load my php on my domain using my javascript that was loaded dynamically.

my sample code

sample.html(Client-side)

```
<div onClick = "getThis()"></div>
```

my.js(Client-side)

```
function getThis(){
var url = "http://www.sampledomain.com/test.js"
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = url;
document.head.appendChild(script); 
}
```

test.js(Server-side)

```
$.get("index.php", function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

index.php(Server-side)

```
<?php 

$_SESSION['user'] = "rob098";

?>

<script>
var data = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['user']) ?>';
</script>
```

but it doesn't alert any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ajax and json:

sample.html

```
<div onClick = "getThis()"></div>
```

my.js (inside sample.html)

```
function getThis() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/test.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      alert(data.user); //should alert rob098
    },
  });
}
```

test.php

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("user" => "rob098"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to append your js file to this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.get("index.php", function(data) {
    alert(data);
});

});
```

so when script file loaded it will execute code inside jQuery ready function

Comment: Tnx for the tip, gonna keep that on my head. But still it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using jquery `$.get()` the wrong way. Well I've never seen used that way at least, so you need to change your index.php to this:

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['user'] = "rob098";
    echo json_encode($_SESSION['user']);

    header('Content-type: application/json');
?>
```

Let me know if I helped.

Comment: Still no luck, tsk. It seems it does not load my php file